# beforeSend like fail and done

Tags: jquery, ajax

Any way to get `beforeSend()` to work like done() and fail() with $.ajax ?

```
$.ajax(..).beforeSend(function(){
  // do things before send
}).done(.....
```

Comment: No, because chained methods on `$.ajax()` are called on the returned object. I can't see any reason why you can't set your `beforeSend` within the `$.ajax` call: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can add `beforeSend:` like `success:`. The event inside `beforeSend:` function works before starting AJAX. This should work

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    data: your_data,
    type:  'get', 
    dataType: 'your data type',
    success: function(data){
        //Do after success
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        //Do before ajax starting
    },
    complete: function(data){
        //Do after completing
    }
});
```

[**Here**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) include details.